# Removing Bearings From Headset

Tags: headset

I was servicing my headset on my Saracen Mantra Elite LSL 2019 but I couldn't remove the bearings, I don't know if there is a way to remove them that I don't know but I thought you were just supposed to pull them out.
[image]
Thanks

Comment: "just pull them out" may mean using a dedicated bearing puller or a cup remover. But I do not know what kind of bearings your headset uses.

Comment: Neither do I, I think they are cartridge Bearings

Comment: Use a pick to pull out the red plastic part which is a retainer for the bearing cone and race. It's a normal bearing race after you get the retaining ring off.

Comment: Does that get it out of the frame?

Comment: You can also remove the cups from the frame but you only do that if you wish to replace the entire headset assembly as the cups are pressed in. For a headset service, you only need to get to the bearing races. It is not a cartridge headset.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get them out, thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to 99Spokes, the [Mantra SL is spec'd](https://99spokes.com/bikes/saracen/2021/mantra-elite-lsl) with a semi-integrated headset. In the S.H.I.S. naming system the upper headset is  ZS44.  This type features a pressed cup into the frame and into the cup a cartridge bearing is a slip fit (doesn't need to be pressed). The cup has a very shallow lip at the top that acts as a stop. Since the system adds very little stack to the head tube, it's known as Zero Stack (ZS).

Yes, the cartridge bearing should just be able to be plucked out by hand.  I wonder if you don't still have a dust seal still in place (I'm looking at the black ring around the perimeter) that is preventing you from removing the cartridge bearing. It looks to be a little too wide for an outer race of a cartridge bearing. The dust seal may sit in a groove machined into the cup so it may take a bit of work to free it from it's seat. Use a pick or small screw driver to remove it.  Take a look at the schematic for your headset. It's number 3 that I think is still in place and blocking the bearing removal.
[image]

Another possibility is that corrosion has somewhat cemented the bearing in the cup. Some penetrating fluid like WD40 may get it loose. Unless you plan on repacking the cartridge bearing with new grease, try to keep the penetrating fluid between the cup and the race. It's mostly solvent and will thin and remove grease should much get past the bearing seals.

Comment: Thanks, there was a small seal holding it in. Got them out easy, thanks